# Conflicting scripts... probably

Tags: javascript, jquery

On [my website](http://gotham-cityrpg.proboards.com/posts/recent), there's a code that adds a couple of elements to the page.  This code is not something that I can edit, and I'm not happy with where it puts these elements because it messes up some of my layout.  So I came up with a little jQuery to move them into a more ideal location - I want them to be siblings of the element that the other code uses for their parents.

```
$('.mini-profile').after(function() {
    var $infection = [$(this).children('.infection_badge'), $(this).children('.infection_button')];
    return $infection;
});
```

And I have a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avalikia/38h4mdbx/2/).

The problem is that this code doesn't work when I add it to the page.  I thought that it might be running before the other script adds the elements so I tried calling it when the window was finished loading, but that didn't work and I'm not sure what else to try.  Is there a way to get this working or am I going to have to come up with another way solve my layout problem?

Comment: i really like the title of this question, +1 :)

Comment: lol, thanks!  I only started learning both JavaScript and jQuery last month so I'm a bit tentative to say that I know for sure that's the problem.  Especially since my website is really complicated because of all the content coming from the board's server - the learning curve to edit the thing has been like running headlong into a brick wall.

Comment: I have already tried both and neither of them work.

Comment: And a timeout?  `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            main();
        }, 1000);
    });`

Comment: You said that the elements you want to move are added by code. You need to make sure that your added code runs after that code. How is that code being executed?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted a comment that I couldn't edit: "Did you try `$(window).load()`? maybe the other script is using `$(document).ready()`". I wanted to say: "Did you try `$(window).load()`? maybe the other script is using it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Forget the rest of my answer (I will keep it because it can contain useful tips for other people) and modify your code to this:

```
$( '.mini-profile' ).after( function() { 
    return $( this ).find( '.infection_badge, .infection_button' ) ; 
});
```

---

I don't think they are "conflicting". That would happen is jQuery is clashing with other JS library. And, as you can read in jQuery's documentation:

> The jQuery library and virtually all of its plugins are contained
>   within the jQuery namespace. As a general rule, global objects are
>   stored inside the jQuery namespace as well, so you shouldn't get a
>   clash between jQuery and any other library... [(read more)](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

If that is actually the problem (you will know it because no jQuery code will work), you can read the rest of that document to learn how to avoid running into conflicts.

But, most likely, jQuery works and your issue is that the external script didn't finish its job when you call your jQuery function.

If you can't edit the other script (and you are sure the jQuery library is properly referenced), you could try this workarounds:

1. Listen for the `$(window).load()` event:

   It will be executed later than `$(document).ready()`, when all the content has been loaded. So, if the other script use it, you can't modify its work with `$(document).ready()`:

   ```
   $(window).load( function() {
       $('.mini-profile').after(function() {
            return [$(this).children('.infection_badge'), $(this).children('.infection_button')];
       });
   });
   ```
2. Set a timeout:

   So you give time to the other code to be executed.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       setTimeout(function() {
           $('.mini-profile').after(function() {
                return [$(this).children('.infection_badge'), $(this).children('.infection_button')];
           });
       }, 1000);
   });
   ```
3. Use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

   As defined in MDN:

   > MutationObserver provides developers a way to react to changes in a
   >   DOM

   So you could wait until the other script modifis that elements to make your own modifications.
4. CSS hacks:

   Sure it is messy, but maybe you can achieve the desired result using just CSS. For example, go to your fiddle, delete all the JS and add this CSS:

   ```
   .infection_button {
       float: left;
       margin-top: 10px;
   }
   ```

   As you see it looks the same. I know that it will get more complicated in your actual layout, but still is something to try out when the rest is failing.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've attempted both #1 and #2, and neither work.  In fact, since I'm dealing with some awful loading times I tried modifying #2 to 30 seconds as a test just to be completely sure that the page has loaded before it fires - I can see the the elements I want moved are in place at that point.  And the code still does not work in that situation.  I have not tried #3 yet because I've never used MutationObserver before and I'm currently trying to understand how it works - the page you linked is a bit over my head.  #4 or similar might be the way I'll have to solve this, but it's hardly ideal.

Comment: But jQuery is working, isn't it? Did you try the same code with other elements?

Comment: I know that jQuery is working on the page in general - it's doing lots of other things on the page with no problems.  I ran a few tests, and I found that if I copy the HTML table from my JSFiddle into my webpage, it does work on that.  But the jQuery only seems to work on that table - it doesn't seem to be identifying elements I'm trying to select properly.

Comment: Check the update, I try it on the console directly over your website.